# jQuery click event doesn't work for dynamically created form field

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms

I am creating a dynamic input field using table row

```js
var i = 1;
$('#add').click(function(){  
  i++; 
  $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><input type="text" id ="lable" name="lable" ></tr>');  
});
     
$('#lable').click(function(){
  alert('called');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
  <td colspan="2">
    <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add Lable</button>
  </td>
</table>
```

but its not calling alert

Comment: Your code has two problem. First: `i` variable doesn't defined. Second:  `click({` should have **function** So change it to `click(function(){`

Comment: @Mohammad Assume `var i=1; ` already defined and `click(function()}` is also there.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you created input dynamicaly, so you should use [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/). That mean using

```
$(document).on("click", '#lable', function(){
```

Instead of

```
$('#lable').click(function(){
```

*Note that you can't have duplicate `id` attribute in html. So use class (`.lable`) instead.*

```js
var i = 1
$('#add').click(function(){  
  i++; 
  $('#dynamic_field').append('<tr id="row'+i+'" class="dynamic-added"><td><input type="text" class="lable" name="lable"></tr>');  
});

$(document).on("click", '.lable', function(){
  alert('called');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<table class="table table-bordered" id="dynamic_field">  
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2">
      <button type="button" name="add" id="add" class="btn btn-success">Add Lable</button>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
```